# MySQL UPDATE only WHERE max()

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, max, where-clause

I'm looking to UPDATE the value of my Table_B from my Table_A where the id matches and where the `Table_A.col1` value is maximal.

Consider that `Table_A` as two columns `B_id` and `col1`. `Table_B` has two columns `id` and `col1`

```
UPDATE Table_A, Table_B
SET Table_B.col1 = Table_A.col1
WHERE  Table_B.id = Table_A.B_id
--WHERE Table_A.col1 is maximal
```

I know that the last line of my query isn't correct but I can't figure out how to use `MAX()` here. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ypercube `SET Table_B.col1 = Table_A.col1` I've edited so it's more clear

Comment: Ah, I just saw the last edit, ok. Let me write the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table_B AS b
  JOIN ( SELECT B_id, MAX(col1) AS max_col1
         FROM Table_A
         GROUP BY B_id
       ) AS a
    ON b.id = a.B_id
SET b.col1 = a.max_col1 ;
```

Comment: This will update all rows of `B` that have a related row in `A`. If it's not working something else is the issue. Edit your question with sample rows of A and B so we can check.

Comment: Sorry, this work like a charm! It's my mistake I forgot the `GROUP BY` when adapting the code to my actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND TableB.col1 = (select MAX(col1) from TableB)
```

(mind the AND instead of WHERE)

Comment: I had this returned: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'Table_B' for update in FROM clause